# Checking if python sqlite table is populated

Tags: python-3.x

Here is my code:

```
dbContent = cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM parse")
if dbContent is None:
    # This should run the nested code if it worked.
```

Instead it runs the else statement which is not what should be happening.

Comment: (1) What 'else statment'? (2) It's obvious that you "want this to work" and we should "please help" in the moment you ask the question, so there's no need for that, in contrary to (1).

Answer (score 0):

I am not a python expert but I think your code is just not correct. Please try this instead:

```
cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM parse")
result=cursor.fetchone()
numRows=result[0]

if numRows == 0:
    # run your code
```

Answer (score 0):

```
dbContent = cursor.execute("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM parse")
rows = dbContent.fetchall()
if not rows:
     ...
```

Lists have implicit booleanness which you can use.